# Keyboard Issues: Can’t sign in or access system preferences

Tags: keyboard

I have an issue where my keyboard is typing random characters when I type, my left and right arrows type a ‘=‘ sign and the numbers don’t work.

I am not signed in and at the login screen. I am unable to type numbers, this is what I need to sign in, and I assume edit the keyboard preferences.

Things I have tried with no results
- Safe Boot
- Reset Cache

Comment: Do you have an external keyboard? Also what type of Mac computer do you have?

Comment: Keyboard preferences can't fix what you describe, sounds like the keyboard is damaged.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use an external keyboard, connect it and then get in and reconfigure in-built keyboard in System Preferences.